# Deliminated layer cuts off imported spreadsheet at row 20

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-2.14, delimiter

Platform: Mac, OS: Mavericks, Qgis: 2.14 Essen

Exporting spread sheet from Excel as Windows .csv. No problem publishing points to map except that import will only process 20 of 23 row entries on spreadsheet. Spreadsheet is consistent. What is the resolution for this?  I can work around by splitting the spread sheet into two separate files but that seems a bit much for something I'm certain I must be missing, a simple oversight?.

Comment: Does reordering the rows in the csv cause different behavior?

Comment: Please share the csv. I'm working with files with thousands of lines. It works if the file is formatted properly.